# Decrypt and convert to ArrayList<MyType>

Tags: java, encryption, type-conversion

I have the following code that successfully allows me to decrypt and convert an encrypted string to the original string:

```
byte[] decryptedtextByte =cipher.doFinal(ciphertext);
String decryptedtext = new String(decryptedtextByte);
```

But when ciphertext is the encrypted text that represents a certain ArrayList cipher.doFinal throws a BadPaddingException error, so in first place I cannot get the corresponding byte array as it happens when what was encrypted was a String

On top of that I can't see how the conversion from that byte[] to ArrayList could be done, I mean if I write something like this:

```
ArrayList<MyType> decryptedtext = (ArrayList<MyType>) (decryptedtextByte);
```

I get the error that they are incompatible types.

What could I do so I can, first, get to properly decrypt the String and then convert it to an ArrayList object?

Comment: How did you convert your `ArrayList` to `String` (or `byte[]`)? It needs to be reversible, if you intend to convert it back to an `ArrayList`.

Comment: I can't understand what is the difference between `encrypted string` and `encrypted text`? where you said allows me to decrypt and convert an encrypted string but not encrypted text.

Comment: You are just show the decryption part, please edit your question and add the code with the conversion "ArrayList<MyType> to byte[]", thanks.